# How to replace outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables. Table A Table B and Table C they have id1,id2,id3 as primary key respectively.

id2 is foreign key in both A and C.

id1 is foreign key in C.

For following query we get five rows

```
     select * 
     from A 
     where id3=123;
```

For following query we get three rows

```
     select * 
     from C 
     where id3=123;
```

To get two remaining rows I performed outer join like

```
     select * 
     from A,B,C 
     where C.id3=123
     AND A.id1=C.id1(+)
```

I am getting required output

Is there any simpler way like in line query or use of "not exist" using which  I can replace outer join ?

Comment: Why do you want to replace the outer join?  It's extremely common, compact, and should perform as fast as any other option.  I would note that `OUTER JOIN` is a preferred syntax since it's standard SQL while the `(+)` notation for Oracle is not - it's only there for backwards compatibility..

Comment: Inline query will be much faster than that but I am getting multiple rows

Comment: Start with the right _results_, then worry about performance.  An inner join gives you the wrong results, so that's not an option.

Comment: Your query will only find the same three rows because of the `where` clause reference to C.id3. (I'm ignoring the spurious references to B). What are you actually trying to do? Find the two rows in A that aren't in C? Get the data from both A and C, with nulls for the C columns if there is no match? Something else? Explain what you're doing, make your queries consistent, and show data and expected results. If you do have something that works and you want a different way to do it then explain why.

Answer (score 1):

You syntax would generate a syntax error.

I speculate that you want to run something like this:

```
select a.*
from a left join
     c
     on a.id3 = c.id3 and a.id1 = c.id1
where a.id3 = 123;
```

However, I don't know what `B` is doing there; it is in the query but no where else in the question.

Comment: My mistake I updated the question what I am looking is way to replace the outer join I am using oracle sql

Comment: @PravinKottawar . . . This syntax has been supported by Oracle for more than a decade.

Comment: Sir I am looking for simpler solutions like in line query or use of not exists

Answer (score 0):

An outer join is the proper mechanism for what you want, but a more standard syntax would be:

```
select * 
from A
LEFT JOIN C 
    ON A.id1=C.id1
WHERE id3=123
```

Comment: what I am looking is way to replace the outer join I am using oracle sql

Comment: I know what you _asked_, but you haven't given a good _reason_ for replacing it - it gives you the right results, is standard, common, and does not have significant performance impact compared to other techniques _that give the right results_.

Comment: @PravinKottawar It's like asking to use something other than `*` for multiplication because `+` is faster.